# Column does not exist in table error

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

I perform a set of operations on a dataset table:

```
MyDataSet sharedDS = new MyDataSet();
MyDataSet referenceDS = new MyDataSet(); 
sharedDS.Table1.Reset(); 
sharedDS.Merge(referenceDS);
```

I get a System.ArgumentException: Column_X does not exist in Table1 if I try to access the column this way:

```
MyDataSet.Table1.FindByKey().Column_X
```

However, this way everything's fine:

```
MyDataSet.Table1.FindByKey()["Column_X"]
```

Can anyone explain what's the issue here?

Reference (originally meant for another problem): [Reset primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764004/reset-primary-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line :

```
sharedDS.Table1.Reset();
```

is causing you trouble.

I think the .reset is clearing the schema. Use .Clear() istead!

Comment: you're right. it is being used to clear the schema. in this case i clear the schema and then copy it from an instance of the same dataset again. now the schema is set but i can only access the column in one particular way. i suspect this could be linked to something similar to: http://kbalertz.com/815545/unhandled-exception-occurs-after-rename-columns-DataSet-object.aspx